# How to subtract sold items based on what has been sold?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am putting together an Inventory Excel Sheet for a Pharmacy. First I have a sheet with the list of Antibiotics:[Running Totals Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpeiq.png)

Then I have a Inventory that contains the Invoice Number and other information based on the antibiotics bought:
[Inventory Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbmCS.png)

First, I'd like to add the total amount of the medication bought, so if for instance I bought 150 Amoxicilin that is spread over 2 invoices, I'd like a total (150 pills). Then I have this other sheet which is a log of how many sold: [Sold Items Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52jah.png). I'd like to subtract the amount sold from the total and display the amount currently in stock. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Using SUMPRODUCT solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*For clear view and better understanding I've used single screen/window, and few of the necessary data only.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Sheet 1 cell B29:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$40:$A$43=$A29)*(Sheet2!$C$40:$C$43))
  ```
- Formula in Sheet 1 cell C29:

  ```
  =$B29-SUMPRODUCT((Sheet3!$A$47:$A$48=$A29)*(Sheet3!$B$47:$B$48))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: THANK YOU, yes this is exactly what I need!

Comment: @KristinVernon ,,  glad to help you,, keep asking ☺